# Dyno pricing confusion

Tags: heroku

The following statements seem contradictory to me

Dynos cost $0.05 per hour, prorated to the second. For example, an app with four dynos is charged $0.20 per hour **for each hour that the four dynos are running.**

Pricing is based on calendar time. If you set your app to four dynos, you will be charged $0.20 per hour **regardless of the traffic your site serves during that time.**

(as seen [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-much-does-a-dyno-cost))

I'm reading it as "you will be charged for a running dyno" then "you will be charged whether or not the dyno is being used"

Please clarify my understanding, because it seems most people don't have this same confusion.

Comment: I read that as "If you set your app to four dynos, it means that you need four dynos and we will charge accordingly until you set the number of dynos to something else."  In other words, "running" is defined as "How many dynos you have set your app to."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Heroku dyno is considered running when it is ready to receive requests, not necessarily when it is actually serving requests. To rephrase:

> For example, an app with four dynos is charged $0.20 per hour for each hour that the four dynos are **provisioned**

Comment: Thanks to both you and Robert Harvey